# Is there a way (or plugin) to quickly access eg. layout/main.xml from R.layout.main in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut

**Like this:(with left click or shortcut)**

[image]

**and that would open main.xml**

It would really save me some time and boredom of browsing it all the time...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hold `CTRL` and hover your cursor over the `R.layout.main`

Make sure the latest ADT-plugin is installed

Comment: @C.d.: When I do this, I got two options: open it in R. or layout file, while the R. option is default. It's one more useless click. Do you know how to make the layout default?

Comment: @Destil: Install the latest ADT plug-in, the default one has been changed with the update I guess.

Comment: @C.d: I have ADT version 21 and Eclipse Juno. Latest it can be. What's your configuration?

Comment: I have checked it and the default one is R for me too. I remember it was not like that before maybe google changed it with the update.

Answer (score 3):

In your Eclipse environment you can press `Shift+Ctrl+R` (short for `Navigate->Open Resource...`) press `m` (main.xml is the first selectable option to me) and press `Enter`

For anything more complex [this should help you...](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_provide_a_keyboard_shortcut_for_my_action%3F)

Comment: Thanks, this is useful as well.